# Windows Version Identification [C/C++]

Tags: c++, c, windows

How would one programmaticly determine the version of windows currently installed?
As in differentiate between vista and xp.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Win32 then you can use [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx) API to identify the OS.

Comment: Sadly, `GetVersion` and `GetVersionEx` are deprecated since W8, in favor of `VerifyVersionInfo`. A poor change, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate question here is what are you trying to test?  It's better to [check for features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832.aspx) than compare version numbers (since there are various cut-down versions of Windows).

[VerifyVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725492.aspx) will do both, and is the recommended way to compare major/minor numbers.

```
BOOL IsAtLeast2008DC() {

  OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi = {0};
  DWORDLONG mask = 0;

  osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
  osvi.dwMajorVersion = 6;
  osvi.dwMinorVersion = 0;
  osvi.wServicePackMajor = 0;
  osvi.wServicePackMinor = 0;
  osvi.wProductType = VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER;


  VER_SET_CONDITION(mask, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
  VER_SET_CONDITION(mask, VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
  VER_SET_CONDITION(mask, VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
  VER_SET_CONDITION(mask, VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
  VER_SET_CONDITION(mask, VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
  VER_SET_CONDITION(mask, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, VER_EQUAL);

  return VerifyVersionInfo(&osvi,
      VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION |
      VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR | VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR |
      VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, 
      mask
      );

}
```

To just test for Vista or later, remove lines that mention product type.  You'll find more examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725491.aspx), but be careful about what you're checking for.

Comment: While this works for testing "Is the current Windows version good enough for my minimum needs?", it does not answer the question that `GetVersionEx` answered: "What version of Windows am I running on?"  Microsoft seems to not want us to ask that question anymore. :(

Comment: Yes, that's deliberate. While the other comment is a direct answer,  it's *usually* not the right solution to a problem.

Comment: As it turns out, I do not need to make decisions on either question.  But I do want to *document* what version of Windows my program gets run on by users.  Without the functionality of `GetVersionEx`, I can't easily do that.  Instead I must estimate the version family with a series of "Is it at least A?" "Is it at least B?" until I find the boundary where the answer changes. Not as satisfactory for my needs.