# Check Windows version

Tags: c++, windows, version

How I can check in C++ if Windows version installed on computer is Windows Vista and higher (Windows 7)?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741294/windows-version-identification-c-c
and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124/how-to-detect-true-windows-version

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Similar to other tests for checking the version of Windows NT:

```
OSVERSIONINFO   vi;

memset (&vi, 0, sizeof vi);
vi .dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof vi;
GetVersionEx (&vi);
if (vi.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT  &&  vi.dwMajorVersion >= 6)
```

Comment: Why must the platform be 32-bit?

Comment: It needs to be sure it isn't 16 bit windows 95/98/ME or Win32s for MajorVersion not to be confused.  I suppose it should allow WIN64 as well, but I can't find the macro name.

Comment: 64 bit Windows has platform ID of VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

Comment: @David:  thanks.  That explains why I couldn't find a 64 bit value.

Comment: This is no longer true. Unless you manifest your application to be Windows-8.1(and above)-aware, `GetVersionEx` will lie to you. This is outlined in [Chuck Walbourn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27324801/1889329).

Comment: @IInspectable:  Thanks.  Maybe you should post another answer.  When I wrote this 4.5 years ago, it *was* true.

Comment: There are others APIs that can retrieve the true OS version number without requiring manifestation, namely `RtlGetVersion()`, `NetServerGetInfo()`, and `NetWkstaGetInfo()` have all been tested and proven to work.

Comment: @wallyk:
There was a 16bit version of Windows ME?

Comment: @Kaiserludi:  Yes, that was how it was [originally released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_ME).

Comment: @wallyk: the linked article does not mention anything about 16bit at all - however https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Windows#Windows_95 mentions that even Windows 95 already only preserved WIN16 for backwards compatibility. If I understand that article correctly, then even Windows 95 already was not available as 16bit OS anymore, but only as 32bit OS that could still run 16bit programs similar to todays 64bit OS being able to run 32bit programs. That would match my memory.

Comment: Sadly, `GetVersionEx` was deprecated in W8, in favor of `VerifyVersionInfo`, which doesn't fill in the current values, merely tests your needs against the current values.

Comment: @JesseChisholm:  Sheesh.  One of Microsoft's most annoying philosophies is that they intentionally force change and obsolescence.  Instead of providing backwards compatibility for features which could be sustained indefinitely.  Note that 7 years ago, when I wrote the answer, it was fully supported.

Comment: @wallyk - Totally agreed on the annoying factor of Microsoft decision making.  The new functionality in `VerifyVersionInfo` is good and useful, but there was no need to deprecate `GetVerionEx`.

Comment: Actually, the code you wrote in this answer is exactly *why* the Microsoft appcompat team pushed to deprecate ``GetVersionEx`` in the first place. Major applications have done this and gotten it wrong since Windows 95. If you want to make a 'you must be this high to ride this ride' check, that's what ``VerifyVersionInfo`` is designed to do robustly and correctly (which is also what the VersionHelpers API wrappers use). As my answer notes, you should be aware that as of Windows 10 VVI has the same manifest-based behavior so you need to plan to add the manifests as well.

Answer (score 30):

All the answers in this thread point you to using `GetVersion` or `GetVersionEx` for this test, which is **incorrect**. It seems to work, but it is risky. The primary source of appcompat problems for Windows OS upgrades comes from poorly written tests based on `GetVersion` results with bad assumptions or buggy comparisons.

**The correct way to do this test is to use `VerifyVersionInfo`, not `GetVersion` or `GetVersionEx`.**

If you are using the VS 2013 compiler toolset and the Windows 8.1 SDK, you can use the `VersionHelpers.h` and just call `IsWindowsVistaOrGreater`.

> If you are using the VS 2013 `v120_xp` platform toolset to target Windows XP, you are actually using the Windows 7.1A SDK, so you need to use `VeriyVersionInfo` directly.

Otherwise, use:

```
bool IsWindowsVistaOrGreater()
{
OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi = {};
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osvi);
DWORDLONG const dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(
    VerSetConditionMask(
    VerSetConditionMask(
            0, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
               VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
               VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
osvi.dwMajorVersion = HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA);
osvi.dwMinorVersion = LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA);
osvi.wServicePackMajor = 0;

return VerifyVersionInfoW(&osvi, VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, dwlConditionMask) != FALSE;
}
```

This code will work on Windows 2000 or later and give you a robust result. If you really needed this test to run on Windows 98 or Windows ME -and- you are using a compiler toolset old enough to actually run on that platform, you'd do the same test but with explicit rather than implicit linking. [What's in a version number?](https://walbourn.github.io/whats-in-a-version-number/)

Furthermore, using `GetVersion` or `GetVersionEx` will by default get the *wrong version* on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. See [Manifest Madness](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/).

> Note that with Windows 10 `VerifyVersionInfo` is also subject to the same manifest-based behavior (i.e. without the GUID element for Windows 10, VVI acts as if the OS version number is 6.2 rather than 10.0. That said, most real-world tests like `IsWindowsVistaOrGreater`, `IsWindows7OrGreater`, `IsWindows7SP1OrGreater`, `IsWindows8OrGreater` are all going to work just fine even without the manifest. It's only if you are using `IsWindows8Point1OrGreater` or `IsWindows10OrGreater` that the manifest-based behavior even matters.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303824/warning-c4996-getversionexw-was-declared-deprecated) stack overflow thread.

Comment: I agree that `VerifyVersionInfo` is the right answer for the OP.  It would always be right if I wanted to ask the question: `Is the current Windows version at least good enough for my minimum needs?` (as the OP does) But the question I _really_ want to answer is `What is the current Windows version?` so I can display it.

Comment: For purely telemetry/support display purposes: In Windows desktop apps, you use ``GetVersionEx``, suppress the deprecation warning, add the compatibility manifest to your EXE, and know that someday it will likely lie. With Universal Windows Platform apps (UWP), you'd use [AnalyticsInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo.aspx). In both cases, don't base any logic at all on the value of the version number or perform any comparisons. If it's for phone support, just tell the user to run ``winver`` and read the string back to you.

Comment: Agreed! But such hoops one must jump through to answer such a simple question (that used to be easy to ask).

Comment: It was always easy to ask "what version of Windows is this?". The harder problem was (a) asking the right question, and (b) knowing what to do with the answer. People screwed this up writing apps for Windows 3 in the early 90s, so it's *always* been challenging to get it right. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040213-00/?p=40633/). With "Windows as a service", the question is also not quite as meaningful as it once was.

Comment: "was" being the important word - it is now hard. And in my case, the purpose is to _display_ the Windows Version, I make no decisions based on the value.  I understand that changing how it is done is to make it harder to ask the wrong question.  But I wasn't asking the question for that decision making purpose.

Comment: "[GetVersionEx may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the Version Helper functions]" per MSDN.. and it's also flagged for deprecation in msvc141 so kudos for this answer. Personally i'd rather have them both available.

Comment: Remember that the warning is really there to get you to look at it at build time instead of making you discover it at runtime. You can either remove the use of the version check API (and replace it with something that's better for appcompat like a QueryInterface test) or suppress the warning and add the manifest entries needed to make it actually work (ideally using ``VerifyVersionInfo`` or the VersionHelpers wrappers for 'you must be this high to ride this ride' tests instead of error-prone conditionals using ``GetVersionEx``)

Answer (score 20):

Use [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx) API function defined in `kernel32.dll`:

```
bool IsWindowsVistaOrHigher() {
   OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
   ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
   osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
   GetVersionEx(&osvi);
   return osvi.dwMajorVersion >= 6;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In Visual Studio 2013 or higher, you can also use the new Version Helper functions.

There are methods for many different Windows versions. Example:

```
#include <VersionHelpers.h>

if (!IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
{
   MessageBox(NULL, "You need at least Windows Vista", "Version Not Supported", MB_OK);
}
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a great option if using VS 2013 and the Windows 8.1 SDK, as long as you are not trying to target Windows XP with the ``v120_xp`` platform toolset which is actually using the Windows 7.1A SDK. There's nothing special about ``VersionHelpers.h`` as it's just utility code for using ``VerifyVersionInfo`.

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer, because it's directly offered by Windows SDK. Beware, for Windows 10 and 8.1 you need an application manifest https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms725492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for the [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Codes above are not enough. Link was helpful.

Comment: Sadly, `GetVersionEx` has been deprecated in favor of `VerifyVersionInfo`.

Answer (score 4):

This [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307394) gives you details for older versions.

> To determine the operating system that is running on a given system, the following data is needed:
>
> ```
>               95  98  ME  NT 4  2000  XP
> PlatformID    1   1   1   2     2     2
> Major version 4   4   4   4     5     5
> Minor version 0   10  90  0     0     1
> ```

You could implement the code and run it on a Vista and Windows-7 machine to check the values returned.

To get the operating system version information make the following call:

```
System::OperatingSystem *osInfo = System::Environment::OSVersion;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the GetVersion() or GetVersionEx() function in the kernel32.dll. This two functions are only available on Windows 2000 or later.

To read more about this look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx.