# Trying to get windows version from C code

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a C application (not c++). Basically the code is in *.c file. I want to add another function to this file to check the windows OS version on which my application is running. I am trying to use the versionhelper functions described below --https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/version-helper-apis. However, when I try to add below header file I get compilation error saying -cannot open source file "VersionHelpers.h" --

```
 #include <VersionHelpers.h>
```

I think this is because my file is a C file. Is there any way to read windows OS version from C code? (Not C++)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive

Comment: @postit: On Windows, the OS version on which you compile is independent from the OS version on which you run.

Comment: Is there a way I can use methods defined in VersionHelpers.h from C code ?

Comment: I've no idea, but your reasoning is wrong. You get that error because your compiler cannot find the header file, not because you have a C program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check Windows version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963992/check-windows-version)

Answer (score 2):

`VersionHelpers.h` is a just an inline header file that does common checks using `VerifyVersionInfo`. You could just use that API directly which is C-callable.

You also need to be aware of the fact that the `GetVersion` and `VerifyVersionInfo` functions are subject to built-in appcompat version lies. See [Manifest Madness](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/10/manifest-madness/) for details.

Of course the real question is what are you actually going to do with that information?

Is this a "you must be this high to ride this ride" test? If so, `VerifyVersionInfo` is the way to do it and what the code in `VersionHelpers.h` does.

Is this a "I need a version for a telemetry or log file" test? In that case you probably want to use `GetVersionEx` and suppress the deprecation warning. Be sure you don't make any runtime decisions based on the value. For UWP apps, you'd use [AnalyticsInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo).

Is this a "I'm checking to see if it's safe to use a particular OS component?" If so, there's likely a better way to do it than an OS check.

See [What’s in a version number?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/02/24/whats-in-a-version-number/)

> The `VersionHelpers.h` header was added in the Windows 8.1 SDK which comes with VS 2013 or later. It's also in every version of the Windows 10 SDK. It is compatible with `.c` as well as `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 1):

VersionHelpers.h is from the Window 8.1 SDK (2014). It didn't ship with VS2012. You have to install it manually, or update to a current Visual Studio version.

Comment: Um. Did you recently have a look at a calendar? Why don't you use VS 2017 and be done with it?

Comment: @Swordfish: Considering there's no such thing as VS2014 (The 2014 date is for Win8.1), I am wondering what he did.